# Show button only after an event is done in android SDK relative view

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk

I have a relative view (Scrollable) in which I have a textview followed by a edittext.
What I am trying to do is when I press enter/done on virtual keyboard for taking input from edittext then only show up the button (saying click to continue) to proceed. If I put the button in xml it is visible before hand so I tried creating the button dynamically in .java file but I am getting an error.
Code given below.

```
    pwd = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pwd);
    pwd.setText(System.getProperty("user.dir").toString()+" $ ");
    command_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.command);
    command_input.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) ||
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)){

                command=command_input.getText().toString();
                System.setProperty("user.dir",command);
                command_output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.command_output);
                command_output.setText("running!");

                Button next = new Button(this); **//error in "this"**
                next.setText("Click To Continue");

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: after creating a view, you still have to add it - you need a reference to the parent view and then `parentView.addView(next)`. I'd suggest that you do put it in the xml and set the visibility instead though

Answer (score 2):

Views visibility is what you're looking for.

There are 3 visibility modes :

- `visible` : by default, the view is shown
- `invisible` : the view is not shown, but takes space (its size) on the layout
- `gone` : the view is not shown, and doesn't take space

So, to answer your question, On your layout :

```
<RelativeLayout 
    .....

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/continueButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Continue"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

On your activity :

```
final Button continueButton = (Button)findViewById (R.id.continueButton);

command_input.setOnKeyListener (new View.OnKeyListener () {
    public boolean onKey (View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction () == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
            continueButton.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a ton man! really appreciate it. Not able to upvote because of low reputation but seriously thanks!

Comment: @KaranNagpal : No worries! you're welcome to accept my answer (the little checkmark below upvote buttons) :)

Answer (score 1):

You are passing incorrect parameter (context) to the create button. You Should use `Button next = new Button(YourActivity.this);` inside any anonymous class.

"this" always refers to the current instance. You are passing "this" inside anonymous class "new View.OnKeyListener", so here "this" is referring to "View.OnKeyListener" instance and not to Activity that extends Context so you are getting error.